# Geomesa export returns no results despite data being present

Tags: geospatial, cql, accumulo, geomesa

Was wondering if you could please help us understand an issue when querying geomesa/Accumulo?

**Issue:**

1. When we query for all fields with `geomesa export -u A -p B -c catalog1 -f d1-json -F csv` it returns data (see below for sample).
2. When we add a subset of columns with `-a "short_text_field"` OR even a simple `-q "short_text_field='Cow'"` it returns 0 features despite the data being present:
   `geomesa export -u A -p B -c catalog1 -f d1-json -F csv -a "short_text_field"`
   INFO Exported 0 features
   id,short_text_field:String,*geom:Point:srid=4326
   INFO Feature export complete to standard out in 2077ms

**Sample data from (1):**

id,geom:Point:srid=4326,short_text_field:String,long_text_field_1:String,long_text_field_2:String
e9c756ef-06d6-42dd-84a9-c774ec9086ec,POINT (-117.830256 -76.799443),597Fish," Cow Car? Cow Fish Mouse Cat Car Fish Horse Mouse Fish"," 诶 迪 伊 迎 益 伊 迎 诶 迎 诶 伊")

Question: Is anyone aware of the best way to debug this?

Excerpt from logs when query is run with -a:

```
2017-01-10 14:36:04,921 WARN  [org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-01-10 14:36:06,448 WARN  [org.apache.accumulo.server.fs.VolumeManagerImpl] dfs.datanode.synconclose set to false in hdfs-site.xml: data loss is possible on hard system reset or power loss
2017-01-10 14:36:09,943 WARN  [org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStore] Configured server-side iterators do not match client version - client version: 1.2.7, server version: unavailable
2017-01-10 14:36:10,329 WARN  [org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator] Error on server testmisc-w-0.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server testmisc-w-0.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:695)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator$QueryTask.run(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:349)
        at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing startMultiScan
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.recv_startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:317)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:297)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:634)
        ... 6 more
2017-01-10 14:36:10,342 WARN  [org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator] Error on server testmisc-w-1.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server testmisc-w-1.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:695)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator$QueryTask.run(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:349)
        at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing startMultiScan
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.recv_startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:317)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:297)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:634)
        ... 6 more
2017-01-10 14:36:10,344 WARN  [org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator] Error on server testmisc-w-1.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server testmisc-w-1.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:695)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator$QueryTask.run(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:349)
        at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing startMultiScan
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.recv_startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:317)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:297)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:634)
        ... 6 more
2017-01-10 14:36:10,351 WARN  [org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator] Error on server testmisc-m.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
rg.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server testmisc-m.c.geobench-146409.internal:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:695)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator$QueryTask.run(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:349)
        at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing startMultiScan
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.recv_startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:317)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.startMultiScan(TabletClientService.java:297)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:634)
        ... 6 more
2017-01-10 14:36:10,430 INFO  [org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.DelimitedExport] Exported 0 features
2017-01-10 14:36:10,433 INFO  [org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.commands.ExportCommand] Feature export complete to standard out in 3049ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to simply add the namespace as a prefix to the ingest and export commands catalog parameter.

When ingesting be sure to specify the namespace.catalogname

Similarly the same must be done when querying.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this answers the question posed. In the question `-c catalog1` is used on both the successful and failing command.

Comment: The keypoint is if you're adding -a or -q to the export command, make sure you prefix the catalog parameter with a namespace.